# Overriding a material-ui theme using withStyles() while already using withTheme()

Tags: css, reactjs, tabs, themes, material-ui

I have been creating a set of reusable components that I had been styling using classes prop to override the MUI classnames.  I then extracted a lot of the common styling into a theme to avoid repetition in the more complex components.  The theme is wrapping each of the components using the `withTheme` HOC.

I am now realising that there are places we need to override the style for one-off cases.  I thought I should be able to do this using the `withStyles` HOC but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Codepen at https://codesandbox.io/s/overriding-a-withtheme-with-withstyle-hoc-0m9cm

MyReusableThemedComponent - is the reusable component (that is really just wrapping Material UI tabs with a theme)

CustomOverideTabs - is my implementation of the MyReusableThemedComponent where I am trying to override the Material-UI textTransform by making the text lower case.

```
const StyledTabs = withStyles({ root: { textTransform: "lowercase" } })(
  MyReusableThemedComponent
);
```

I believe the transform: uppercase is the default for the MuiTab-root class, but even specifying it in the theme doesn't seem to make a difference.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect of `withStyles` is to inject a `classes` prop into the wrapped component (`MyReusableThemedComponent` in your case), but you aren't doing anything with that injected prop except passing the entire `props` object to `useStyles` during the creation of `tabsStyle`. This will merge the two sets of classes, but then you would need to leverage `tabsStyle.root` somewhere to have any effect.

You have the following code for rendering the `Tab` elements:

```
            <Tab
              key={index}
              label={tab.tabTitle ? tab.tabTitle.toString() : "tab" + { index }}
              disabled={tab.disabled}
              classes={{
                root: tabsStyle.tabRoot,
                selected: tabsStyle.selectedTab
              }}
            />
```

This is leveraging `tabsStyle.tabRoot` as the `root` class, but `tabRoot` hasn't been defined anywhere. The `textTransform` works as intended if you change this to `root: tabsStyle.root`, or if you leave the `Tab` rendering unchanged, you can get it to work by changing the rule name in your `withStyles` call to be `tabRoot` (e.g. `withStyles({ tabRoot: { textTransform: "lowercase" } })`).

Example using `tabsStyle.tabRoot` (i.e. only changing the `withStyles` argument): https://codesandbox.io/s/overriding-a-withtheme-with-withstyle-hoc-fxybe

Example using `tabsStyle.root` (i.e. only changing how the `classes` prop is specified when rendering the `Tab` elements): https://codesandbox.io/s/overriding-a-withtheme-with-withstyle-hoc-ptj87

---

A separate issue in your sandbox is that you appear to be trying to specify style overrides in the theme in `ConditionalThemeWrapper`, but the structure of the theme is incorrect. The `MuiFab` and `MuiTab` entries in the theme should be within an `overrides` key. Here is a modified version of your sandbox demonstrating this: https://codesandbox.io/s/overriding-a-withtheme-with-withstyle-hoc-ju296

Related documentation:

- https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#global-theme-override

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide such a complete answer and clear explanation.  
  (The comment regarding the missing 'overrides' keyword was my mistake in cutting down the theme for the sandbox - I accidentally removed it. Very well spotted .)